# Java Regular expression not of some character followed by a word or starting with word

Tags: java, regex

I would like to find a pattern where `[^#$%_-]COMMENT` should be true and string "COMMENT" should also be true.

```
Case 1 : @COMMENT true
Case 2 : #COMMENT false
Case 3 : COMMENT true
```

For Case 3 i am getting false
My regular expression is `[^#\'\"$%_-|]COMMENT`

Comment: Please share the code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Range warning: `_-|` = \x5F-\x7C

Comment: just add a `?` after your character class `[...]` if you want to make it optional

Comment: You really need to work on stating your requirements more clearly. Now I see in comments that you want to check for spaces after the forbidden character as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a lookbehind assertion `(?<![#$%'_"-])COMMENT`
Stringed `"(?<![#$%'_\"-])COMMENT"`

If you actually want to match the character before, as well as comment,
it would be this `\S?(?<![#$%_-])COMMENT`
Stringed `"\\S?(?<![#$%'_\"-])COMMENT"`

Load up the class with `[stuff not allowed]`.
When you use the class inside a negative assertion, you don't need the
negated class `[^]` anymore since it is positively addressed as not allowed
via a negative assertion.

Comment: @illusion - What? Impossible. Show me .. It doesn't fail for any of them.

Comment: on the first one you seem to be missing a parenthesis. on the second one... why would you not just use `[^...]?` ?

Comment: I am not able to add \" and \' inside the not allowed ones

Comment: @illusion - I added the stringed versions.

Comment: @PatrickParker -  `[^...]?` will always match. It matches nothing. So having `[^@]?COMMENT` will match any @`COMMENT` it sees. If you're just reading group 0, the `@` won't show be there, but it will match any comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.
`^[^#$%-]?COMMENT$`
[^#$%-]? -> not contain any of these characters.

```
String c1 = "@COMMENT";
String c2 = "#COMMENT";
String c3 = "COMMENT";
System.out.println(c1.matches("^[^#$%-]?COMMENT$"));
System.out.println(c2.matches("^[^#$%-]?COMMENT$"));
System.out.println(c3.matches("^[^#$%-]?COMMENT$"));
```

Comment: lot of unnecessary backslashes there

Comment: I can have the [#$%-]\sCOMMENT. This fails

Comment: try `?` instead of `\s`

Comment: also don't use `\s` in Java, use double escape `\\s` but it fails i tested.

Answer (score 0):

the corrrect java regex for our case would be 
`String regex = "[^#\'\\"\$%\-|]COMMENT"`

You can test the output at [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but it failed for case 3